# Deleting apps from iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm having this problem in iTunes Connect where I want to delete an old app project I did, but when I click "app information", there is no "Delete App" option. Any help?

Comment: Now you can https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682672/5306470

Answer (score 3):

**Deleting an App**

> If you’ve created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need to
>   manage, you can delete it from iTunes Connect.
>
> Apps can’t be deleted if they are part of a Game Center group, in an
>   app bundle, or currently displayed on a store. You’ll want to remove
>   the app from sale or from the group if you want to delete it. See
>   Removing an App from Sale or Removing an App from a Group in Game
>   Center Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect. Apps that have not been
>   approved yet can’t be deleted; instead, reject the app. See Removing a
>   Build from Review.

Following is Screen shot of delete application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[More detail follow below apple official document.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)